# How can I print a Dataframe from Tkinter Treeview?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, tkinter

I am trying to print a Dataframe from a Tkinter Treeview. In this case, I have 10 items in total. (check screenshot below) [image]

By using the following code;

```
row_list = []
 columns = ('Index','DrugsName', 'NumberWasted','MoneyWasted','Date')
 for child in treeview.get_children():
     row_list.append(treeview.item(child)["values"])
    
      treeview_df = pd.DataFrame(row_list, columns=columns)
    

     print(treeview_df)
```

I am getting this output in the terminal;

```
Index   DrugsName  NumberWasted  MoneyWasted     Date
0      1  vancomycin             1          300  11/2/21
   Index   DrugsName  NumberWasted  MoneyWasted     Date
0      1  vancomycin             1          300  11/2/21
1      2   meropenem             2          150  11/2/21
   Index   DrugsName  NumberWasted  MoneyWasted     Date
0      1  vancomycin             1          300  11/2/21
1      2   meropenem             2          150  11/2/21
2      3  gentamicin             3          200  11/2/21
   Index   DrugsName  NumberWasted  MoneyWasted     Date
0      1  vancomycin             1          300  11/2/21
1      2   meropenem             2          150  11/2/21
2      3  gentamicin             3          200  11/2/21
3      4  micafungin             1           90  11/2/21
   Index     DrugsName  NumberWasted  MoneyWasted     Date
0      1    vancomycin             1          300  11/2/21
1      2     meropenem             2          150  11/2/21
2      3    gentamicin             3          200  11/2/21
3      4    micafungin             1           90  11/2/21
4      5  amphotericin             3          400  11/2/21
   Index     DrugsName  NumberWasted  MoneyWasted     Date
0      1    vancomycin             1          300  11/2/21
1      2     meropenem             2          150  11/2/21
2      3    gentamicin             3          200  11/2/21
3      4    micafungin             1           90  11/2/21
4      5  amphotericin             3          400  11/2/21
5      6     Cefazolin             2          250  11/2/21
   Index     DrugsName  NumberWasted  MoneyWasted     Date
0      1    vancomycin             1          300  11/2/21
1      2     meropenem             2          150  11/2/21
2      3    gentamicin             3          200  11/2/21
3      4    micafungin             1           90  11/2/21
4      5  amphotericin             3          400  11/2/21
5      6     Cefazolin             2          250  11/2/21
6      7      Oxytocin             2         2000  11/2/21
   Index     DrugsName  NumberWasted  MoneyWasted     Date
0      1    vancomycin             1          300  11/2/21
1      2     meropenem             2          150  11/2/21
2      3    gentamicin             3          200  11/2/21
3      4    micafungin             1           90  11/2/21
4      5  amphotericin             3          400  11/2/21
5      6     Cefazolin             2          250  11/2/21
6      7      Oxytocin             2         2000  11/2/21
7      8       Insulin             1         1500  11/2/21
   Index     DrugsName  NumberWasted  MoneyWasted     Date
0      1    vancomycin             1          300  11/2/21
1      2     meropenem             2          150  11/2/21
2      3    gentamicin             3          200  11/2/21
3      4    micafungin             1           90  11/2/21
4      5  amphotericin             3          400  11/2/21
5      6     Cefazolin             2          250  11/2/21
6      7      Oxytocin             2         2000  11/2/21
7      8       Insulin             1         1500  11/2/21
8      9      Thiamine             1          100  11/2/21
   Index     DrugsName  NumberWasted  MoneyWasted     Date
0      1    vancomycin             1          300  11/2/21
1      2     meropenem             2          150  11/2/21
2      3    gentamicin             3          200  11/2/21
3      4    micafungin             1           90  11/2/21
4      5  amphotericin             3          400  11/2/21
5      6     Cefazolin             2          250  11/2/21
6      7      Oxytocin             2         2000  11/2/21
7      8       Insulin             1         1500  11/2/21
8      9      Thiamine             1          100  11/2/21
9     10  Penicillin G             2          250  11/2/21
```

As you can see the code I am using print multiple Dataframes that are equal to the number of rows I have in the Treeview. Please, could help me to write code that print only the last Dataframe with 10 index.

I want to see this in the terminal;

```
  
   Index     DrugsName  NumberWasted  MoneyWasted     Date
0      1    vancomycin             1          300  11/2/21
1      2     meropenem             2          150  11/2/21
2      3    gentamicin             3          200  11/2/21
3      4    micafungin             1           90  11/2/21
4      5  amphotericin             3          400  11/2/21
5      6     Cefazolin             2          250  11/2/21
6      7      Oxytocin             2         2000  11/2/21
7      8       Insulin             1         1500  11/2/21
8      9      Thiamine             1          100  11/2/21
9     10  Penicillin G             2          250  11/2/21
```

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because you are calling the print method from within your for loop.

Removing your print statement from your loop should fix the issue.

```
 row_list = []
 columns = ('Index','DrugsName', 'NumberWasted','MoneyWasted','Date')
 
 for child in treeview.get_children():
     row_list.append(treeview.item(child)["values"])

 """
 The line below should also be removed from the for loop 
 because you are re initializing the data frame 
 on every iteration of the loop. """
 
 treeview_df = pd.DataFrame(row_list, columns=columns)     

 print(treeview_df) # Notice here the difference in indention level of this print statement
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: For added speed and efficiency, you could also indent the `treeview_df = pd.DataFrame(row_list, columns=columns)` line to the level of `print(treeview_df)`. It would do virtually the same thing, but would be less time-consuming, because it doesn't repeatedly assign `treeview_df` when only the last value is being used. @TheoN: If this answer was satisfactory, please accept it.

Comment: great point! And should definitely be done. Glad you caught that! It has been a long day at work! Ty Sylvester!

Comment: I have updated my answer based on Sylvester's comment